# Shell script : compare two files and string matching problem : The arguments to this comparison can never be equal

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Given file structure :

```
~/
 |__compressed_files/
 |__student_id
```

where `compressed_files` contains `.zip` `.rar` `.tar.gz` and `.dika` file format.

For simplicity :

`student_id` file be like :

```
A00003
A00001
A00002
A00004
A00005
...
```

`compressed_files/` directory be like :

```
A00002.dika
A00004.zip
A00003.rar
A00001.tar.gz
...
```

Both `compressed_files` and `student_list` contents are listed randomly, not numerically.

----------------------------------------------First Step----------------------------------------------------

I want to use the `student_id` file list to find out :

who did not hand in files, which categorized into `missing_list`

who hand in the incorrect file format, which is `.dika` file format, categorizing into `wrong_list`

Expected outcome will be :

`missing_list` :

```
A00005
...
```

`wrong_list`

```
A00002
...
```

Expected outcome file structure be like :

```
~/
 |__compressed_files/
 |__student_id
 |__missing_list
 |__wrong_list
```

Here is my solution to it :

Use nested for loop to check whether ids in `student_list` are existed in  `compressed_files` or not by checking file format.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Create missing_list and wrong_list in ~/ directories :
touch ~/missing_list  ~/wrong_list

# Use student_id file to compare with compressed_files :
for i in $(more ~/student_id)
do
    for j in $(ls -l ~/compressed_files/ | awk -F  ' '  '{print $9}')
    do
        if [[ "$i" == "$j | $(awk -F '.' '{print $1}' ~/compressed_files)" && "$j | $(awk -F '.' '{print $2}' ~/compressed_files)" == "dika" ]]
        then
                echo "$j" >> wrong_list
        elif [[ "$i" == "$j | $(awk -F '.' '{print $1}' ~/compressed_files)" ]]
        then
                true
        else
                echo "$i" >> missing_list
        fi
    done
done
```

`$j | $(awk -F '.' '{print $1}' ~/compressed_files)` is like `A00002` from `A00002.dika`

`$j | $(awk -F '.' '{print $2}' ~/compressed_files)` is like `dika` from `A00002.dika`

I used https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check, but found out below `==` in `$j | $(awk -F '.' '{print $2}' ~/compressed_files)" == "dika" ]]` prompted :

```
^-- SC2193 (warning): The arguments to this comparison can never be equal. Make sure your syntax is correct.
```

I checked wrong message and searched some syntax problem like `[` `[[` or  `$()` `${}` or string matching problem but cannot got what I expected.

Sorry for lengthy description but I just want to deliver my problem clear.

Can anyone help me out and corrected based on my script? Thanks!

Comment: If you create and post a [mcve] (emphasis on **minimal**) you'll get more people with the time/energy to read that to help you.

Answer (score 0):

*`"$j | $(awk -F '.' '{print $1}' ~/compressed_files)"`* and *`"$j | $(awk -F '.' '{print $2}' ~/compressed_files)"`* are somewhat complicated attempts to get the base name and extension, respectively, and they don't work because pipelines aren't interpreted when quoted. You can use [*Shell Parameter Expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `"${j%.*}"` and `"${j#*.}"` for that.